# Spinor normalizations in Breit-frame: electric and magnetic form factors

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, spinors, protons

We usually have the normalization (see e.g. page 110 in Halzen & Martin "Quarks and Leptons")

$$u^{(r)\dagger}u^{(s)} = 2E\delta_{rs}$$ which leads to 
$${\bar{u}^{(s)}}u^{(s)} = 2m. $$

According to the authors of the cited book, in the Breit frame in elastic electron proton scattering$^2$, the normalizations are instead$^1$:

$${\bar{u}^{(s)}}u^{(s)} = 2E. $$
and
$$u^{(s)\dagger}u^{(s)} = 2m$$

How is this possible? How can the normalization change because of frame change?

---

$^1$It seems really strange why the normalization should change by changing frame.

$^2$ The Breit frame is defined by $\vec{p}'=-\vec{p}$ where the three momenta are those of the out and incoming protons respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so it's not a question of normalization. My confusion arose because of naïvety.

$$\tag{1} u^{(r)\dagger}u^{(s)} = 2E\delta_{rs}$$
$$\tag{2} {\bar{u}^{(s)}}u^{(s)} = 2m.$$
Since the normalization relations $(1)$ and $(2)$ applies to same momenta spinors i.e. $\bar{u}(p)[\cdots]u(p)$ and so on.

If one is not as lazy as me, one can easily derive the result claimed by the authors. The result follows from the normalization and the explicit form of the spinors, ($E>0$ "positive energy")

$$u^{(s)}(\vec{p}) = N\begin{bmatrix}
       \chi^{(s)}   \\[0.3em]
       \frac{\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}}{E+m}\chi^{(s)}  
     \end{bmatrix}$$
where $N=\sqrt{E+m},s=1,2$ and 
$$\chi^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$\chi^{(2)}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1
\end{bmatrix}.$$